# How to avoid rotation animation jumping at 2π boundary?

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation

I am animating an arrowhead along a CGPath using a CAKeyframeAnimation. The arrowhead follows the path, except for when the output of `atan2` 'flips' from 0 to 2π or vice versa. In this case, the arrowhead does a complete 360° spin before continuing.

**Is there any way to compute the values of my CAKeyframeAnimation so that the arrowhead always rotates the smallest amount to get where it's going?**

```
        let turnAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        turnAnimation.duration = 5

        var values = [CGFloat]()
        for i in 0..<points.count - 1 {

            let point1 = points[i]
            let point2 = points[i + 1]
            let delta = point2 - point1
            let value = atan2(delta.y, delta.x)

            values.append(value)
        }

        turnAnimation.values = values
        turnAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        turnAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        arrowPointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(values.first!, 0, 0, 1)
        arrowPointLayer.add(turnAnimation, forKey: "rotateArrow")
```

EDIT: Updated based on answer, but still not quite working:

```
let turnAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        turnAnimation.duration = 5

        var rawValues = [CGFloat]()
        var values = [CGFloat]()
        for i in 0..<points.count - 1 {

            let point1 = points[i]
            let point2 = points[i + 1]
            let delta = point2 - point1
            let rawValue = atan2(delta.y, delta.x)

            var value: CGFloat

            if i == 0 {
                value = 0 // we will apply this value from rawValues
            } else {
                let lastValue = rawValues.last!
                value = rawValue - lastValue
            }

            if value < 0 {
                value = .pi * 2 + value
            }

            rawValues.append(rawValue)

            values.append(value)
        }

        for (i, p) in values.enumerated() {
            print("\(rawValues[i]): \(p)")
        }

        turnAnimation.values = values
        turnAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        turnAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        turnAnimation.isAdditive = true

        arrowPointLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rawValues.first!, 0, 0, 1)
        arrowPointLayer.add(turnAnimation, forKey: "rotateArrow")
```

Comment: Hi again - it occurs to me suddenly that the problem may be the use of `"transform.rotation"` as the key path. Apple advises against doing that.

Comment: Really? What instead, just `rotation`?

Comment: Just transform. You can use the Value Function to specify z rotation.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! Do you have a link for the "apple advises" part? I'd like to read their info on all this for future reference.

Comment: It was years ago in a WWDC video. He said that successive rotations using a key of "transform.rotation.z" could cause math trouble.  And that is why I use the value function in this example in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_keyframe_animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making `values` a list of absolute rotation values, make it a list of rotational *differences* and set the animation's `isAdditive` to `true`. That way, *you* are telling the arrow which way to turn and by how much.

I tested like this (in my test, `v` is just some view sitting in my interface):

```
let turnAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
turnAnimation.duration = 5
let values : [CGFloat] = [0,2,-1,2,-1,3,-3]
turnAnimation.values = values
turnAnimation.timingFunction = 
    CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
turnAnimation.isAdditive = true
self.v.layer.add(turnAnimation, forKey: "rotateArrow")
```

The view behaved exactly as I expected.

Comment: Conceptually this is great! Unfortunately when I implement it the arrow completely stops rotating ::scratches head::

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like _now_. I only know what it looked like originally. I assure you that it does work. I'll add a simple example as a test.

Comment: Cool, thanks, but I'd also be curious to know what went wrong. :)

Comment: You are killing the animation by setting the `transform` property directly, maybe. You'll notice I didn't do that in my code. As an experiment, you might cut that line and see if it helps any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126022/discussion-between-buildsucceeded-and-matt).